# Battery Drain Immediatly

Tags: chevrolet, audio, wiring, ground, corvette

So, I am currently putting in a finalized sound system in a 1998 C5 corvette.
I finally put the whole thing together( 4 speakers, hooked to an Alpine amp with RCAs. And a amp included sub box, the basic Dual box.
It took me all day and I finally got it wired throughout the car. Here is the problem, both the amp and the sub are grounded to the drivers side factory ground but. When I reconnected the battery and turned it on to test it however, the ground was not tightened down well. Now the lower fuse box below the passenger dash makes a very strange sound and while the vehicle is running the power gradually drains the battery to zero!!!!!
I'm completely at a loss someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the sound a rapid ticking sound oe more like a buzz? Does it continue having issues with the ground terminal fully tightened?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the sound. And I think I got it, the belt fell. Therefore, no power to the alternator. I have heard C5 corvettes have infamous problems with their flywheels throwing the belt.

Comment: Check the ground point that wasn't tightened: due to arcing, the metal surfaces may have been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

So I might have found a solution! Cars have these crazy things called alternators. Well I googled the issue and most people seem to say if you are having this problem its because the alternator is bad. Well I checked mine and the craziest thing, the belt had thrown itself..... In the garage.... wow. 
Anyway, if you have problems sounding like this check the alternator. If I get the belt back on I will see if things get better.